# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name'). thisProduct undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with reading {find}.
The problem is in ProductDetail.js.
First, click on the products link than on any product to see details.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'find')
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-product-detail-pages-dynamic-links-forked-y1o0n?file=/src/ProductDetail.js:418-429

Comment: You are using `===` while comparing a string to an integer. Either use `==` or do `sneakers.find((product) => product.id + "" === productId + "");` or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done some mistakes over there in your `ProductDetail.js` file.

##### First:

You can use `useEffect` hook to check and compare if there is a `matching id` or not.

##### Second:

You can use `useState` hook to store the `thisProduct` and update the `thisProduct` value by calling `setThisProduct` and use it in the `JSXElement`.

This is always a best practice to use the `state` for data set and get.

> Here is more about [React.Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

##### Third:

`Price` is a Object and you can't render your object like that, so use the key instead of object while rendering. like this: `{thisProduct?.price?.current?.value}`

> You can learn more about [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

##### Fourth:

`productId` which you're getting from `useParams` is a string type, and your `productId` from sneakers is a number type. So you need to change your `productId` to number while comparing like this: `Number(productId)`

> Learn about [Numbers in Js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Here is the complete code of yours:

```js
// ProductDetail.js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { StateContext } from "./GlobalContext";

function ProductDetail() {
  const { productId } = useParams();
  const { sneakers } = useContext(StateContext);
  const [thisProduct, setThisProduct] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sneakers) {
      const findProduct = sneakers.find((product) => {
        return product.id === Number(productId);
      });
      console.log("findproduct", findProduct);
      setThisProduct(findProduct);
    }
  }, [productId, sneakers]);

  return (
    <div>
      {thisProduct && (
        <>
          <h1>{thisProduct?.name}</h1>
          <p>Price: {thisProduct?.price?.current?.value}</p>
          <p>{thisProduct?.description}</p>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductDetail;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

completely check your state and props, it is not providing valid data to child component

```
<StateContext.Provider value={{ sneakers }}>
      {console.log(sneakers, "== thisProduct")}
      {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
```

console will show your data, it coming null so that is the issue